# How to add rows just after table head and just before tfoot when working with html table by jquery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

just see my table html example. please guide me how could i add rows just after table head and just before tfoot when working with html table by jquery.

```
<table class="webgrid-table" id="sampletable">
    <thead>
        <tr class="webgrid-header">
            <th scope="col">
                <a href="http://localhost:13562/page1">ID ?</a>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <a href="http://localhost:13562/page1">First Name</a>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <a href="http://localhost:13562/page1">Last Name</a>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <a href="http://localhost:13562/page1">State Name</a>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <a href="http://localhost:13562/page1">City Name</a>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                IsActive
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr class="webgrid-footer">
            <td colspan="6">
                <div id="content">

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="webgrid-row-style">
            <td class="SmallCols">1</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Amit</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Ghosh</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">West Bengal</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Kolkata</td>
            <td class="text-center checkbox-width SmallCols">
                <input type="checkbox" id="select" class="box" name="select" checked="'checked'" value="True">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-alternating-row">
            <td class="SmallCols">2</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Tridip</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Bhattacharjee</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Bihar</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">DharBganga</td>
            <td class="text-center checkbox-width SmallCols">
                <input type="checkbox" id="select" class="box" name="select" checked="'checked'" value="True">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

i tried with this script but not getting expected result.

```
 var rows = "<tr>"
                + "<td class='customertd'>" + item.CustomerID + "</td>"
                + "<td class='customertd'>" + item.CompanyName + "</td>"
                + "<td class='customertd'>" + item.ContactName + "</td>"
                + "<td class='customertd'>" + item.ContactTitle + "</td>"
                + "<td class='customertd'>" + item.City + "</td>"
                + "<td class='customertd'>" + item.Phone + "</td>"
                +"</tr>";
                $('#tblCustomers tbody').append(rows);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following for that table in your example.

```
$("#sampletable tbody").append(rows);
```

the # represents the ID you wish to find and you have tblCustomers in your jQuery example.

Comment: where the new will be append because i need to append row just after table header. `append(rows)` will append row at the last row ?

Comment: Just as an idea why are you inserting rows into a table this way?

Comment: i need to insert rows into table dynamically.....then discuss what is the best way to achieve it.

Comment: Append just adds elements to the selector you have specified in the jquery.

Comment: What do you mean by a row before tfoot?  The last row in the tbody?

Comment: Yes I know :). You add rows to thead, tbody or tfoot.  Adding a row just before tfoot is not a good idea.

Comment: See the updated fiddle that works. 
https://jsfiddle.net/L8yjd4hf/1/

Just be aware you were adding a phone number to the column that has the IsActive data inside of it.

Comment: thanks for your code. can u tell me how to add row before tfoot tag?

Comment: The idea of having the thead, tbody and tfoot elements would be to contain the rows of the table in a set way.

I have updated the fiddle to show you what I mean.
https://jsfiddle.net/L8yjd4hf/3/

Answer (score 0):

`$('#tblCustomers tbody').append(rows);` check the Selector 'tblCustomers' in your HTML is the id 'sampletable'